# Boost:: compressed folder tar.gz format

Tags: c++, boost

I search a code to compressed a folder in tar.gz archive format.
I work on Linux with Boost.

Comment: @Praetorian Sorry to waste all these close votes, but that wasn't a correct duplicate. The OP's merely looking for code how to compress a folder to tar gz, not to find compressed folders in a directory.

Comment: Why not simply call `tar` using `system()`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oops, you're right. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't call system because i work on embedded system&that's not authorized the system() function

Comment: Then you need to find a library that does archiving. AFAIK, there's nothing in Boost that does that. Boost.Serialization can create compressed archives from data, but that's not the same as compressing an existing folder.

Comment: @GaetanGriffonDuBellay Lookup the [LZMA library](http://7-zip.org/). We're using it on an embedded system sucessfully. And please don't ask such off-topic questions in the future.

Comment: are you sure? 
I realy thinks  boost can create some archives.

Comment: @GaetanGriffonDuBellay He already mentioned boost's serialization library. The doubt is about the input (an existing folder).

Comment: i have an existing folder with some files & i need to compress it on tar.gz format so yea, in input i search to send an existing folder.

Answer (score 2):

Boost doesn't have support for tar/zip/... archives.

For that, the most comprehensive library I know is `libarchive`, which is used by many reputable projects, and supports all of the above.

You would still us e.g. Boost Iostreams compression filters to arrive at a compressed tar in that case.